# Show Django where to find my static files, with an alternative settings folder setup

Tags: css, django

I have followed this [guide](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/), to set up a slightly different/better django project.

I am also trying to use static files, to load site wide files (like a site.css file for every page). To do so I'm following this [guide](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/css/README.html) also.

What I'm finding is that it's looking for `http://localhost:8000/static/css/site.css` to grab my css, when the css (on disk) is `top-level-folder/static/css/site.css`, and for context,  `top-level-folder` is also where I've got my app and project folders, as well as manage.py (that is, `app_folder`, `project folder` and `manage.py` are siblings with the shared parent of `top-level-folder`).

Something like this:

```
top-folder
    |-> app-folder (same name as top-folder)
    |-> project-folder (same name as top-folder)
    |-> static
```

My concern is that this isn't being found, as rather than having a `settings.py` file, I have a settings *folder* with several files in it (the base one is called `base.py`) as per the first [guide](http://www.revsys.com/blog/2014/nov/21/recommended-django-project-layout/).

Here's the relevant snippet from my base.py

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gantt_charts/templates/gantt_charts')]
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
                    )
```

And I also have this in there by default, `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` but I don't know if that's relevant.

So why doesn't Django know where my .css file is? Is it to do with my alternative set up?

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand your layout. Can you maybe post the output of `tree`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman is that better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing your directory structure, it would be better to just change the BASE_DIR to reflect the extra level you have introduced:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

With that small change you can keep your static folder in the "right" place.

Comment: I've just tried this and now everything is broken...I'm trying to fix it now as I agree it should be in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

I've edited my settings (base.py) and I've moved my static folder.

Both the top level folder and the app have the same name, so I was getting which folder to put it in mixed up.

I now have:

```
top-folder
    |-> project-folder (same name as top-folder)
        |-> static
    |-> app-folder
```

Rather than:

```
top-folder
    |-> app-folder (same name as top-folder)
    |-> project-folder (same name as top-folder)
    |-> static
```

My basy.py snippit now looks like:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gantt_charts/templates/gantt_charts')]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
                    ]
```

See how I've nestled a `os.path.abspath` in there? That's the other important step I think.

Also worth noting that you can add debugging print-outs to your settings (it's Python code after all) which really helped. For instance:

```
print ("Base Dir is at:",BASE_DIR)
print ("Static Dir is at:",STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

And this runs each time the runserver command triggers.