# Why doesn't the template block of my page load, after changing where BASE_DIR is located in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27858577/1075247) advice, and it seems to have broken my template loading.

Directory declarations in my 'settings.py':

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'gantt_charts\\templates\\gantt_charts')]
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
                    ]
```

Views.py for my app:

```
def project_list(request):
    projects = Project.objects.filter(tasks__isnull=False).order_by('updated_date').distinct()
    return render(request, 'project_list.html', {'projects':projects})

def project_detail(request,project_id):
    projects = get_object_or_404(Project,pk=project_id)
    return render(request,'project_detail.html',{'projects':projects})
```

My apps urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?:project)?/?$', views.project_list),
    url(r'^project/(?P<project_id>\d+)/\w{0,50}',views.project_detail),
)
```

My project_list.html (which lives inside `gantt_charts\\templates\\gantt_charts`):

```
{% extends 'base.html'%}
{% block content %}
{% load humanize %}
{% load staticfiles %}
    {% for project in projects|slice:":3"%}
        <div class="project">
            <h3>
                <a href="project/{{project.id}}/{{project.slug}}" title="Created {{project.created_date|naturaltime}}">{{project.title}}</a>
            </h3>
            <ul>
                {% for task in project.tasks.all|slice:":3" %}
                <li>{{task.title}}</li>
                {% empty %}
                <li>No tasks in this project</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

And my base.html template (which lives in `templates`):

```
{% load humanize %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- external includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- local includes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/site.css' %}">
        <title>gAnttlr - Gantt charts</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-header fixed-div">
            <h1>gAnttlr</h1> 
            <img src ="{%static 'svg/antler3.svg'%}" class="antler-icon fit-div" alt="Medium sized antler">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    {% block content %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="push"></div>
        <div id="footer" class="muted">
            <p>
                gAnttlr logo derived from 'Vectorised' by Yug (Nordisk familjebok (1911), vol.15, p.19 [1]) [Public domain], <a href="http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3AKronhjortshornets_utveckling%2C_Nordisk_familjebok.svg">via Wikimedia Commons</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's what I think should be happening:

1. When I go to the url specified as `r'^(?:project)?/?$` (either `localhost/` or `localhost/project`)

   1. Find it wants to look up `views.project_list` and go there,
2. See it wants to render `project_list.html`, look that up over the TEMPLATE_DIRS, and find it.
3. In `project_list.html` see it needs to involve `base.html`, look that up over the TEMPLATE_DIRS, and find it.
4. Stitch the two html files together, fill in the other variables from database queries, and then load.

What I get though is *just* the base.html page, and nothing else. I can't see why that would be. All I can think is that it's trying to find `project_list.html` in the `'templates'` dir, not find it and just give up. Interestingly if I specify the location of base as anything but `'base.html'` (like prepending a dir, then it throws an error up and doesn't render anything.

Why isn't django loading `project_list.html` in place of the `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` meta-tags?

Comment: Since you see the contents of `base.html` that means the template is properly resolved (`project_list.html` extends `base.html`). Normally the problem lies within `project_list.html`'s content block. For example, maybe the `projects` variable is empty? Have you tried putting html outside of the projects forloop to see if it gets rendered?

Comment: @ppetrid I haven't as it was working until I moved the location of my `base.html`, and altered my base_dir location. I'll have a poke and report back. Thanks

Comment: @ppetrid Spot on! The thing is I had this before due to a mistake I made that was about blocks and templates, so I see why I didn't look past it.

Comment: Great, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advice I followed was to change where my BASE_DIR pointed also had the unfortunate effect of telling django that my db had moved too, as that was placed relative to BASE_DIR.

I've fixed this and made it a 'constant' at the same place as my other *_DIR variables, so I can keep track of it changing.

I've also added an `{% empty %}` block to the for loop, to alert me of this in the future.